# Alignment on Same line when converting to PDF with Itext c#

Tags: c#, html

hi i have a code i am using

```
            using (var doc = new Document())
        {
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
            {
                doc.Open();
                var example_html = data;
                    using (var srHtml = new StringReader(example_html))
                {
                    iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                }

                doc.Close();
            }
        }
```

and i have HTML

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">Programuli uzrunvelyopis sistemis sheqmnisas da&nbsp;</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">momsaxurebis xelshekruleba</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">
 <br></br>
</p>

<p style="text-align:left;">This text is left aligned<span style="float:right;">This text is right aligned</span></p>

<p>
 <br></br>
</p>

<p>ertis mriv blabada raradwadaw rada rarada rarada (shemdgomsghi &quot;&quot;) blabladd</p>

<p>
 <br></br>
</p>

<p><strong><span style="font-size: 36px;">terminalta ganmarteba</span></strong></p>

<ul>
 <li>dadarara</li>
 <li>arararara</li>
 <li>atatatata</li>
</ul>
```

All works perfectly but  this This text is left alignedThis text is right aligned

here is how it works 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bePyc.png)

and here is how i need 
[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zjyk.png)

Any suggestions??

Comment: Have you tried using a `<div>` with two `labels` instead of `<p>`?

Comment: can you give me code sample ?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/4cr5j61v) example should give you a good idea of how it's done. It uses CSS so I don't know if it is what you're actually looking for. Also, I left your code and you can see that it works in the example I gave you so probably the `<span>` is not being parsed correctly.

Comment: when i convert it in pdf it doesnt work anymore ... i mean they are side by side.. you did same with my code and it worked for you ?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/KPKkl8X) this is the result i get